# Captain crunch - ROT13 encoder program

Tags: java, string, encode

The Captain Crunch decoder ring works by taking each letter in a string and adding 13 to it. For example, 'a' becomes 'n' and 'b' becomes 'o'. The letters "wrap around" at the end, so 'z' becomes 'm'.

This is what I've got after editing it a bit from peoples comments, but now it keeps telling me that output may have not been initialized and I have no clue why... also is there anything else I need to fix in my program?

*In this case, I am only concerned with encoding lowercase characters*

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class captainCrunch {
 public static void main (String[] Args) {

 Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
 String input;

 System.out.print("getting input");
 System.out.println("please enter word: ");
 input= sc.next();

 System.out.print(" ");
 System.out.print("posting output");
 System.out.print("encoding" + input + " results in: " + encode(input));
 }//end of main


 public static String encode(String input){

 System.out.print(input.length());
 int length= input.length();
 int index;
 String output;
 char c;
 String temp= " ";

        for (index = 0; index < length; index++) {

            c = input.charAt(index);
            if       (c >= 'a' && c <= 'm') c += 13;
            else if     (c >= 'n' && c <= 'z') c -= 13;
            output= temp + (char)(c);
        }
        return output;
    }

}
```

Comment: you're trying to implement an algorithm called "rot13". you can find a basic example here: http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/31datatype/Rot13.java.html Just replace the System.print calls to your string (or better stringBuilder) and you're good to go.

Comment: What do you want to happen with upper-case versus lower-case?  Although you can convert `char`s this way (and probably works for an assignment like this), there are things besides letters in the space - numbers, punctuation marks, some accented characters, "whitespace" (tabs, spaces, etc).  So, you need to figure out what the start and end of your valid range is.  You may want the modulo operator (`%`).  You also have to hit every character in the string, so you will need some sort of loop...

Answer (score 1):

It's called ROT13 encoding.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ROT13

To fix your algorithm you just need:

```
public static String encodeString (String input) {
    StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i=0;i<input.length;i++) {
        char c = input.charAt(i)
        output.append(c+13); // Note you will need your code to wrap the value around here
    }

    return output.toString();
}
```

I haven't implemented the "wrapping" since it depends on what case you need to support (upper or lower) etc. Essentially all you need to do though is look at the range of c and then either add or subtract 13 depending on where it is in the ASCII character set.

Comment: I know the official name is `ROT13`, and I know it's an implementation of the `Caesar Cipher`, but *please please please* can we call it the CCDR (Captain Crunch Decoder Ring) Algorithm. **Please**.

Comment: Since you said please, henceforth it shall be known as the CRCCDR (Chris' Requested Captain Crunch Decoder Ring) Algorithm.

Comment: did i miss something about captain crunch?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any loop iterating over the character of your string. You have to iterate other the string from `0` to `string.length()`.

Answer (score 0):

The output may have not been initialized:

```
String output = "";
```

If you don't put `= ""` then you have never initialized it (it's essentially random garbage, so the compiler won't let you do it).